# Error Number 1096 - Showing Total from Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to show GRAND TOTAL of my table from database, but I'm face trouble like this picture below

[image]

And here is my Model code:

```
public function total()
    {
        $totl = array();
        $this->db->query('SELECT SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(tgl_inpt) = YEARWEEK(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)), omz, 0)) as yestr FROM mzharian INTO @yst;');
        $this->db->query('SELECT SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(tgl_inpt) = YEARWEEK(NOW()), omz, 0))  as now FROM mzharian INTO @now;');
        $this->db->query('SELECT (SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(tgl_inpt) = YEARWEEK(NOW()), omz, 0))-SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(tgl_inpt) = YEARWEEK(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)), omz, 0))) as selisih FROM mzharian INTO @selisih;');
        $this->db->query(' SELECT namatoko, tgl_inpt, omz, SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(tgl_inpt) = YEARWEEK(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)), omz, 0)) as yestr, SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(tgl_inpt) = YEARWEEK(NOW()), omz, 0))  as now, (SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(tgl_inpt) = YEARWEEK(NOW()), omz, 0))-SUM(IF(YEARWEEK(tgl_inpt) = YEARWEEK(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)), omz, 0))) as selisih
        FROM mzharian
        INNER JOIN toko ON mzharian.toko=toko.idtoko
        WHERE YEARWEEK(tgl_inpt) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(),1)
        GROUP BY idtoko
            UNION
        SELECT "TOTAL", null, null, ROUND(@yst), ROUND(@now), ROUND(@selisih) ORDER BY tgl_inpt ASC');

        $query= $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $totl = $query->result();
        }

        return $totl;
    }
```

Yet the result I expected is like this picture below

[image]

can anybody here help me find out what happen? Thank you.

Comment: According to the error you're not specifying a table to select